# Spring @Component & @Bean annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I believe `@Configuration` annotation when used in conjunction with `@Bean`  annotation in spring is used to replace xml configuration. However I saw a piece of code where `@Bean` was used in conjunction with `@Component` (defined at class level). Is this a valid declaration? Are there any any pros / cons in using `@Component` with `@Bean` annotation vs using `@Configuration` and `@Bean`.

**EDIT:**

Thanks @Sundar & @Biju. I did programmatic call between 2 bean methods under Component class. I saw different object values. However when I used Configuration , I saw the same bean values. Based on what you had explained , I assume a regular method call was made when I used `@Component` , whereas when I used `@Configuration` , I assume method annotated with `@Bean` was treated as a Spring Bean

**Code**

```
@Component
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="customerService")
    public CustomerService getCustomerService(){
        System.out.println(getService());
        System.out.println(getService());
        return getService();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerService getService(){
        return new CustomerServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
com.company.service.CustomerServiceImpl@68bbe345
com.company.service.CustomerServiceImpl@30b8a058
```

**Code**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean(name="customerService")
    public CustomerService getCustomerService(){
        System.out.println(getService());
        System.out.println(getService());
        return getService();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomerService getService(){
        return new CustomerServiceImpl();
    }
}
```

**Console Output**

```
com.company.service.CustomerServiceImpl@71623278
com.company.service.CustomerServiceImpl@71623278
```

Comment: another key difference: one is "inside" and the other "outside" the bean... so `@Bean` potentially might know *nothing* about (can be decoupled from) `org.springframework.*`..while an "annotated class" can't/won't/ *is spring dependent*

Comment: the first observation should (version resp.) comply with ["lite" beans](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts); the latter with "Note:
Trying to inject the results from @Bean methods on the same configuration class is effectively a self-reference scenario as well..." [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Answer (score 4):

It is a valid declaration, however there are catches - the one within a `@Component` is referred to as a lite-mode and dependencies cannot easily be injected for beans declared in this form. The recommendation is always to use `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` annotated class - here is a good reference on this - http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-basic-concepts

Comment: Thanks @Biju! I have updated my question. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: The behavior seems to be the same both with and without @Component. Are there any differences if I use Bean in class annotated with Component vs no annotation.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `@Component` as an alternative for `@Configuration`. It’s official [suggestion from spring team](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12833).

Simply declare your `@Bean` methods on classes not annotated with `@Configuration` (but typically with another Spring stereotype instead, e.g. `@Component`). **As long as you don’t do programmatic calls between your `@Bean` methods**, this is going to work just as fine, but conditions apply*.

Please refer more info in this link.

http://dimafeng.com/2015/08/29/spring-configuration_vs_component/

Comment: Thanks @Sundararaj! I have updated my question.Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.learnjavaupdate.com/2023/04/difference-between-bean-and-component.html

> 1. Purpose: `@Bean` is used to explicitly declare a single bean. It is typically used to configure third-party objects that are not under the
>    control of Spring, or to create beans that require some customization
>    beyond what can be achieved using component scanning. On the other
>    hand, `@Component` is used to automatically detect and register all
>    classes marked as components in the application context.
> 2. Configuration: Beans defined using `@Bean` are typically created in configuration classes that are annotated with `@Configuration`. These
>    classes contain methods that return instances of the beans that are to
>    be managed by the Spring container. In contrast, `@Component` is used
>    to mark any class as a Spring-managed component that can be injected
>    into other objects.
> 3. Scoping: `@Bean` can be used to configure bean scope, while `@Component` does not offer this feature. This means that beans
>    created using `@Bean` can be defined with specific scopes, such as
>    prototype or singleton, whereas beans created using `@Component` are
>    typically singletons by default.
> 4. Flexibility: `@Bean` provides greater flexibility than `@Component`, since it allows for programmatic instantiation and
>    configuration of the bean, as well as more control over the bean's
>    lifecycle. On the other hand, `@Component` is simpler and more
>    declarative, allowing Spring to automatically detect and manage the
>    components without requiring any explicit configuration.

Comment: When quoting external resources, please make sure to actually quote it.